# How to have Postfix send email to another server if user lookup fails for specific domains

Tags: postfix, smtp

Currently my server acts as a gateway, checks AD for valid email addresses, if the email address exists in exchange it sends over the email, otherwise just rejects (typical)

I need Postfix to send any emails with specific domains to other servers (not same network).

Steps would go something like this:

get requested email
check if email exists in AD
if it doesn't exist, check if the domain is in a file and send that email to a server specified in that file

Is this even possible?  I looked at smtp_fallback_relay but the second email is checked, it get rejected if not found in AD

Answer (score 1):

Postfix will verify validity before any routing is performed, so that order must be respected.

Put your valid recipient lists for exchange and the other destinations in one of the appropriate maps, and then put both in sequential transport_maps; you can make it not change the routing by just specifying `joe@foo.bar smtp:` as the RHS.

Comment: Let's say I have something like this:

relay_recipient_maps = ldap:/etc/postfix/ldapusers.cf, hash:/etc/postfix/secondary

/etc/postfix/secondary would have something like:
@hello.com OK

How can i have two transport maps for the same domain, and only use a particular transport map depending on if the email address is located in exchange?  If an address well@hello.com is in exchange, use trasport_map1, but if it doesn't, use transport_map2.

Comment: In the way I indicated above: place one after the other.

Comment: but i would have to have hello.com domain listed in both transport tables, just with different destinations.  wouldn't the first transport table be used at all times?  assume that i do not know the exact email addresses hosted at the remote server.

Comment: i noticed that if i specify the exact email address in the second transport map, the setup works.  however, if i set it up as catchall (@hello.com smtp:server.com), that gets ignored and the first transport table is used.

Comment: Don't use catchalls.

Comment: unfortunately it's not an option